# Redirects in htaccess from parent and subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After searching all the other solutions I haven't found a working example on stackoverflow.

My main website redirects accordingly, but when I want to do they same thing to a subfolder/admin folder it inherits the parents search patterns and does not use the landing page in the admin folder.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2  [R=301,L]
```

To allow access to the admin sub folder I have another htaccess file that has:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

To clarify I do attempt to turn this folders htaccess on so I can redirect the queries, only leaving it off has successfully accessed the admin sub folder, but any trailing query is back to the main site.

I've tried the following on both htaccess files

```
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php             [QSA,L]
```

Turning it off and then back on in the sub directory htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteEngine On
```

Please advise thanks.

Comment: Not clear what problem are you facing in `admin` folder. Can you clarify the problem.

Comment: @anubhava - The htaccess in the main site is the one listed above. With the second htaccess in the admin folder turned off it will allow me to access /admin/index.php if not any of the url such as site.com/admin/page/ will inherit the parents htaccess. I do not want anything from the admin folder using the parent htaccess file. I want anything that is site.com/admin/whatever/ to land on site.com/admin/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

**`DocumentRoot/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# strip spaces
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2  [R=301,L]

## add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,NE,L]
```

**`/admin/.htaccess`**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# forward everything to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. I'd upvote you if I could. I tried that /admin/ rewrite base in the admin folder. The only part I did notice is  that the strip space and add - in admin doesn't work. I don't think its going to be needed there anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. If you're going to need space removal rule in `/admin/` then add `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\ (.*)$ $1-$2  [R=301,L]` below `RewriteBase /admin/` line.